# How to estimate the time and memory requirement for Sparse and variational Gaussian Process (SVGP) with minibatch approach

Tags: gaussian-process, time-complexity, scalability

I'm implementing Sparse and variational Gaussian Process (SVGP) using [GPflow library](https://gpflow.github.io/GPflow/develop/notebooks/advanced/gps_for_big_data.html) using minibatches. I've been trying to search for details regarding the time and memory complexities e.g. [from this source](http://gpss.cc/gpss20/slides/Dai2020.pdf), but it remains a bit unclear how to get these estimates.

I basically have a data matrix consisting from about two million data points with 28 input features, that is a data set $\mathcal{D}_{2,000,000 \times 28}$ matrix consisting from Python float-type numbers (64 bit = 8 bytes), and so my data matrix size in memory is roughly about 500 MB.

In my machine learning process, I perform model hyperparameter and feature selection using cross-validation and genetic algorithm. I also take advantage of multicore processing for speeding up the computations. What I would like have, is an estimate on how much computational  time and memory my process takes (I'm using a supercomputer so I need to estimate the required resources). For estimating the complexity of my process, I need to estimate how much time and memory one minibatch -based gradient descent -like step in the SVGP takes, as I've understood that SVGP is an iterative process, desgined to tackle the scalability of Gaussian Process model by using a similar process as in deep neural networks, that is, batch learning (using subset of the data in each training iteration).

**So my questions is: Given that I have a subset of my data matrix of size $N\times 28$ ($N$ data points, $28$ features), how can I estimate 1) how long one iteration of SVGP fitting takes and 2) how much memory I need in this iteration. Basically I'm asking the time and memory complexities here per minibatch iteration.**

Comment: Time is nigh impossible to say because it will depend on factors that we might not even know. (e.g. the BLAS/LAPACK libraries installed, sample properties - "ease" of the problem, etc.) For the memory your best bet is to run a smaller sample in your local system, we know that it "should be" $O(nm)$ but that is just the order, it might have certain leading factors that change things substantially in practice.